# ggplot2 Font on PDF error message: "Font Family not found"

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, fonts

I am having a problem of getting Fontawesome5 to work in R. I have installed the latest version of R, and therefore all have updates all the packages used as well, and I can't get the font to work in R. It is used to make info graphics, see the website here: https://www.listendata.com/2019/06/create-infographics-with-r.html

Once I upload the ttf. files into R i get this error message:
In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label),  ... :
font family 'FontAwesome5Free-Solid' not found, will use 'wqy-microhei' instead

This means that I get a plot back with no font in it, just a dot. (see picture) [R plot without font[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyNiU.png)

It would appear R can't put Fontawesome5(5th version) onto the ggplot2/pdf. Is there a way to make this font work in R with ggplot?, regards James.

```
    library(ggplot2)
library(waffle)
library(extrafont)
library(tidyverse)
library(echarts4r)
library(echarts4r.assets)

install.packages("extrafontdb", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")

library(extrafont)

#font download: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf

extrafont::font_import (path="C:/file/location/Documents/R", pattern = "awesome", prompt = FALSE)

install_fa_fonts()
extrafont::font_import (path="C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/waffle/fonts") #path is where R installs file:

loadfonts(device = "win") #loads in fonts

fonts()[grep("Awesome", fonts())] # should say Awesome fonts 5 in installed. 


waffle(
  c(`Poor=10` =10, `Average=18` = 18, `Excellent=7` =7), rows = 5, colors = c("#FD6F6F", "#93FB98", "#D5D9DD"),
  use_glyph = "female", glyph_size = 12 ,title = 'Girls Performance', legend_pos="bottom"
)
```

Comment: I'm having the same kind of problem and have yet to find a solution after researching for weeks. It happened after updating my Mac OS to Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after I had updated my `Mac OS` to `Catalina`. After weeks of research (and minutes after I had commented on your post here), I found a solution that at least worked for me.

It seems (but please correct me if I'm wrong) that the R package `extrafont` can only deal with `.ttf` font files. And it seems like `Catalina` converted my fonts to `.ttc`, so I had to convert these back into `.ttf` and copy paste these `.ttf` into the System fonts folder.

**In short, convert your fonts from `.ttc` to `.ttf`**

Similar to what they figured out here:
https://github.com/wch/extrafont/issues/32

I used `transfonter.org` to convert my fonts.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was great.